# RESTful resource creation in multiple steps

Tags: api, rest, api-design, restful-authentication

There are situations where resource creation requires more than one step.

### Example

A session resource is created when a user authenticates. So the API call responsible for authentication would be a `POST` to `example.com/api/sessions`.

We use a password-authenticated key exchange for authentication. This requires the sending of two messages to the server: `AuthInit` and `AuthFinish`. The session should only be created once the user is authenticated (after successful processing of `AuthFinish`).

**But since there are now two steps to creating a session, where should each of the two requests be send?**

### Potential Solution 1: two endpoints

`AuthInit` -> `example.com/api/sessions/init`

`AuthFinish` -> `example.com/api/sessions/finish`

### Potential Solution 2: one endpoint handles both

`AuthInit` -> `example.com/api/sessions`

`AuthFinish` -> `example.com/api/sessions`